# wget without an extension

Tags: curl, wget, scraperwiki

I am downloading data from the CDC. I want to download all .txt files from a given directory. This code worked for 2017 because all download links ended with .txt. In 2016, all links download to a .txt (if you manually click) but there is no such extension in the link address. I have also tried to download using -A "*Export* to search for all "Export Data" links but this hasn't worked.  I would appreciate any help!

wget -A txt -m -p -E -k -K -np https://wonder.cdc.gov/nndss/nndss_weekly_tables_menu.asp?mmwr_year=2016&mmwr_week=01'